# Beamer: Alignment of Justified Caption in List Environments

Tags: beamer, captions, lists, subcaption

Figure/Table captions are supposed to be justified in my beamer presentations. Caption and subcaption packages are included for the aforementioned and other purposes. The captions are now justified, but their alignment is not right within list environments as shown the below figure.

[image]

A MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[justification=justified,width=\linewidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\justifying

\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 1 }- A figure with very long caption. since it is outside list environments, it fits rightly to the text-width, with no unwanted indentation. This paragraph is justified using ragged2e package for proper comparison.}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item Now let us introduce an environment.

\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 2 }- A figure with very long caption. since it is inside a list environment, it does not fit rightly to the linewidth, hence crossing the right margin. The caption appears justified though.}
\end{figure}

\item When caption-setup is included inside figure environment, the caption width is fine, but it creates unwanted indentation. 
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 3 }- A figure with very long caption. The width is okay, but because of unwanted indentation, it crosses the right margin here as well. The caption is justified here as well.}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Without caption and subcaption packages, this problem is gone along with caption justification. Because of many reasons, a fix which does not exclude caption/subcaption packages is prefered. Thanks in advance for any help related to this.

Comment: The package `beamer` has own mechanism for captions. It not work well with `caption` nor `subcaption` packages. Styles for captions are defined  by `\setbeamertemplate{caption}`, `\setbeamerfont{caption}`, etc. If you remove loading `caption` and `subcaption` from preamble, caption will no longer spill out of right text area border.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the additional indentation of the `itemize` environment, that is added to the `linewidth`. Therefore we have to subtract this indentation in the definition of the width of your caption.
You can use `\captionsetup{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}` for that.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[justification=justified,width=\linewidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 1 }- A figure with very long caption. since it is outside list environments, it fits rightly to the text-width, with no unwanted indentation. This paragraph is justified using ragged2e package for proper comparison.}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\captionsetup{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}

\item Now let us introduce an environment.

\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 2 }- A figure with very long caption. since it is inside a list environment, it does not fit rightly to the linewidth, hence crossing the right margin. The caption appears justified though.}
\end{figure}

\item When caption-setup is included inside figure environment, the caption width is fine, but it creates unwanted indentation. 
\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{Caption 3 }- A figure with very long caption. The width is okay, but because of unwanted indentation, it crosses the right margin here as well. The caption is justified here as well.}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nico, but it is not working for me, even after updating all the associated packages to the latest. Are you by chance using an old version of any of the aforementioned packages?

Comment: I used overleaf to compile it and got no errors or warnings. They currently use TeX Live 2019 as distribution. What kind of error do you geht?

Comment: I don't know why but wen I compile it locally on my computer it seems to have no effect. As a workaround you can wrap the whole `itemize`-environment inside a `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}
 ... \end{minipage}` environment. This worked for me. Maybe someone else knows the reason for that behaviour?